# SQL Query return zero row using notORM php

Tags: php, pdo, notorm

Issue: SQl Query return zero row using notORM.

Steps taken to fix it but didnt work:

1. Check connection db -> no error, connection established
2. Check instance initialization -> obj inst. created succesfully
3. Check syntax -> no error
4. Check table name exist || !exist -> table name exist
5. Check no. of row in table rates_call either rows > 0 || = 0 -> no. of rows > 0

Code:

```
require 'NotORM.php';
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password) or die ("can't connect");
$db = new NotORM($conn) or die ("instance not created");
$rates = array();
foreach($db->rates_call() as $rate)   
{ 
   $rates[] = array(
    "country_name" => $rate[country_name],
    "rate" => $rate[rates] 
   ); 
   echo "in foreach loop";
}
echo json_encode($rates);
```

Based on the code, the foreach loop not executed bcoz the no. of row returned is zero but in my database table, having few line of rows. I already tried using PDO aswell, it returned zero result also. Appreciate your assistant.

Comment: So, you expect us to imagine `rates_call` code, right?

Comment: @u_mulder The rates_call() method returns multi-dimensional array with the rates_call table's as primary key column as the first-level index. Read the notORM documentation, http://www.notorm.com/ documentation for further details.

Answer (score 0):

I did silly mistake at my PDO connection...

I wrote:

```
  $dsn = 'mysql:host:localhost;dbname=dtbasname';
```

It should be like this

```
  $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dtbasname';
```

I accidentaly wrote ':' instead of '=' in between host and localhost.